FP Movement along the wall makes the character move faster and glitches out a little
First Person Movement along the wall makes the character move faster and glitches out a little.
The problem is pretty much visible here:
https://youtu.be/_1dDdCSwVEo
Source:
https://github.com/CryptoMares/FPS-Player-Controller
How would you fix it?
Thanks for your help!
UPDATE: Switching to JoltPhysics (https://github.com/godot-jolt/godot-jolt) seems to have eliminated the glitches at least.

The video doesn't clearly display increased speed when touching a wall.

True, but it does visibly increase, even though it doesn't register with velocity length.


When wish_dir passes through the wall, due to physical collision, the final velocity of the object in this frame will be parallel to the wall. What happens in this frame and next is:

Use dot to find the projection of the current velocity to wish_dir, and make some restrictions on speed changes, and finally get add_speed.
Use velocity + add_speed * wish_dir to get the velocity of the next frame(v2).
This frame ends and the engine physics calculation is entered. Since v2 passes through the wall, the velocity component perpendicular to the wall is discarded.
Go to the next frame. At this time velocity is v2', which is larger than v1.
Calculate friction. This causes v2' to become smaller. When v2' is larger, the speed of reduction through friction is greater. When v2' becomes larger and larger each frame, at a certain moment, the acceleration effect of v2' will be offset by the friction force calculation, so that the object moves at a constant speed.

The fundamental problem is that max_velocity should be used to limit the final velocity rather than the length of the add_speed component during acceleration.
func accelerate(wish_dir: Vector3, max_velocity: float, delta):
    var add_speed = MAX_ACCELERATION * delta
    var new_velocity = velocity + add_speed * wish_dir
    new_velocity.y = 0
    var new_speed = min(new_velocity.length(),max_velocity)
    new_velocity = new_velocity.normalized() * new_speed
    new_velocity.y = velocity.y
    return new_velocity

As for the glitch, this problem also exists in the sample project:


This is very interesting, but it didn't didn't work unfortunately + it broke jump. Did it work perfectly on your end? In any case, thanks for taking the time.

@ThetaJones Yes, it works fine for me. You can use print(velocity.length()) to output and observe the speed, it will not exceed MAX_VELOCITY_GROUND.

What about those small glitches? (See: https://youtu.be/_1dDdCSwVEo) Are they gone too on your end?

@ThetaJones Yes, those glitches also hapen to me. And I think it's a internal bug in move_and_slide because when I try to change the collision shape to BoxShape3D, they just disapeared.

Thanks for confirming. But nothing like this is happening in this example: https://github.com/EthanTheEnigma/quake-godot-4-tutorial
So it must be something with this particular code that I have at the moment.

Can you please try his solution on your end? It didn't fix the problem and broke jump on my end.

@ThetaJones Breaking the jump is because the acceleration process should be calculated in the xz plane, I've edited the code to fix this. As for the fault, after confirming that the sample project you gave also has this problem, I have attached a picture of the test results.

Oh damn, you're right... Anyway, thanks a lot! You have a big brain.

FYI: Jolt Physics fixed the glitchiness.

var current_speed = velocity.normalized().dot(wish_dir)

velocity should be normalized before dot product

Thanks, but this does not fix the problem though. It's still going faster along the wall and there are still these micro-glitches.

@ThetaJones
i did try it in godot and when the vel was not normalized it was obvious by printing the vel that it indeed gets bigger along the wall it doesn't happen when vel is normalized

But did you see the video that demonstrates the problem? That's what I would like to fix, pretty much.

yes is did that before cloning the repo though I'm pretty sure @mangata answer works better
